# Bounding Hessian by Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Say $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded, smooth open domain.

I'm encountering inequalities of the sort

$$||\nabla u||_{L^4(\Omega)}\leq||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1/2}||\Delta u||_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1/2}$$

I know that Gagliardo Nirenberg interpolation would give us

$$||\nabla u||_{L^4(\Omega)}\leq||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1/2}||\nabla u||_{H^1(\Omega)}^{1/2}$$
What I know about $u$ is that it solves either (but not both) zero Dirichlet boundary conditions or zero Neumann boundary conditions. How does the latter inequality lead to the former?

Comment: Just to be sure, there is no Hessian $\nabla^2 u$ in your question, right?

Comment: There isn't. So essentially they're bounding the Hessian with the Laplacian. And having thought about this since posting my question, I recalled that this kind of bound is possible via elliptic estimates if $u$ is sufficiently smooth with zero trace. So I guess that answers part of my question. But what if all we know is that $u$ has zero Neumann boundary conditions?